# The Nivo Slider library could not be found

Tags: 7, drush, installation

This is the first time I use a CMS, and I'm trying to install nivo slider module into Drupal. I used the following commands

```bsh
drush dl nivo_slider
drush en nivo_slider -y
```

Then I added some pictures to the slider but they are displayed without animation

And in the status report I have the following error message

> Nivo Slider jQuery plugin Not installed
>   The Nivo Slider library could not be found.

Comment: Did you take a look at the readme.txt file in the module?

Comment: thanks, but now I can't see the slides, although the block is visible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Nivo Slider Requirements

- [Libraries API](http://drupal.org/project/libraries)
- [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update)

You need to download the [Nivo Slider Plugin](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/) and extract it to sites/all/libraries. The extracted folder must be named nivo-slider.

Comment: The folder name is essential. If downloading the release from GitHub, the folder will be named something like Nivo-Slider-3.2 by default (matching the archive). You must either rename it or extract to your own folder named "nivo-slider".

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the field settings in the Views module; check the format settings.

This is for a view using the [Views Nivo Slider](http://drupal.org/project/views_nivo_slider) module.

[image: screenshot]

This is for a field formatting using the [Nivo Slider](http://drupal.org/project/nivo_slider) module.

[image: screenshot]

See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60520/nivo-slider-is-not-working-properly